# Laravel MySQL apply product filters with eloquent (what is the correct query?)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to filter my products with eloquent but my where statement for the filters would never work the way I have it currently.

My database tables look like this:

The `products` table

```
+---------------+
| id | name     |
+---------------+
| 1  | product1 | 
| 2  | product2 |
| 3  | product3 | 
| 4  | product4 |
+---------------+
```

The `properties` table

```
+------------------------------------+
| id | property_group_id | value(int)|
+------------------------------------|
| 1  | 1                 | 20        |
| 2  | 1                 | 10        |
| 3  | 2                 | 2         |
| 4  | 2                 | 4         |
+------------------------------------+
```

The `products_properties` table

```
+--------------------------+
| product_id | property_id | 
+--------------------------|
| 1          | 1           |
| 1          | 3           |
| 2          | 2           |
| 2          | 4           |
+--------------------------+
```

The SQL I'm currently generating with Eloquent looks like this:

```
select * from `products` 
    where exists (
        select * from `properties`
            inner join `products_properties` 
                on `properties`.`id` = `products_properties`.`property_id` 
            where `products`.`id` = `products_properties`.`product_id` and 
            (
                `properties`.`property_group_id` = 1 and <--- property_group_id is not 
                `properties`.`value` >= 15 and                1 and 2 at the same time
                `properties`.`value` <= 25
            ) 
            and 
            (
                `properties`.`property_group_id` = 2 and
                `properties`.`value` >= 1 and 
                `properties`.`value` <= 2
            )
    )
```

I'm looking for `product1` with this query but this will never happen since the `property_group_id's` don't match at the same row. Using an OR between the 2 where statements will also not work since only 1 of them has to be true to find something.

The SQL is generated like this in Eloquent:

```
$products = Product::with(['properties' => function($query){
        $query->with('propertyGroup');
    }])
    ->whereHas('properties', function ($query) {
        // Use filter when filter params are passed
        if(array_key_exists('filterGroupIds', $this->filter) && count($this->filter['filterGroupIds']) > 0){

            // Loop through filters
            foreach($this->filter['filterGroupIds'] as $filter){
                // Add where for each filter
                $query->where(
                    [
                        ["properties.property_group_id", "=", $filter['id']], // 1 or 2
                        ["properties.value", ">=", $filter['min']], // 15 or 1
                        ["properties.value", "<=", $filter['max']]  // 1 or 2
                    ]
                );
            }
        }

    })
    ->get();
```

What will be the correct query to get the right result back? And if possible how will my Eloquent code look like to generate this query?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to acomplish?

Comment: @lessan a product filter. I'm looking for product1 with my query but my current where statement would never work.

Comment: yes, i understood that, but what is the criteria you are filtering after? value of the property? id of the property? explain a little,in english, not in code what are the filters that you want to apply

Comment: @lessan pretty much based on the value in the `properties` table. The user picks a range of 2 values for a group and if the property value falls between this range the product should be found. This works fine at the moment with just 1 filter but the moment I have multiple filters my query won't work as shown in my question above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use one `whereHas()` clause per `$filter`:

```
$products = Product::with('properties.propertyGroup');
if(array_key_exists('filterGroupIds', $this->filter) && count($this->filter['filterGroupIds']) > 0) {
    foreach($this->filter['filterGroupIds'] as $filter) {
        $products->whereHas('properties', function ($query) {
            $query->where([...]);
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM properties p 
WHERE p.value BETWEEN minval AND maxval
JOIN product_properties pp ON p.id = pp.property_id
JOIN products pr ON pr.id = pp.product_id
```

Note that this query hasn't been optimized at all since i don't know exactly the desired data and behaviour
Also the filtering is made by the property id, not by the group id, if you want by the group just change

```
p.id = pp.property_id
```

to

```
p.property_group_id = pp.property_id
```

For the eloquent part, try doing it on your own and post the code, you need to define the relations between the models firstly though